# Are there any packages for creating charts?

Tags: packages, graphics

I'm looking for a package in which you can create nice bar and/or line charts in LaTeX. Currently I'm plotting the charts in Calc (OpenOffice), export it to a PDF document, crop it and then including it as graphics.

I reckon there should be some more efficient way of doing this, preferably entirely in LaTeX.

Comment: See also: [Best way to draw a bar chart in LaTeX?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2979097/562769)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can take a look at [PGF/TikZ](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/), then on top of that is [pgfplots](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgfplots/). To see it in action, see [TeXample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/).

Comment: pgfplots certianly is a good choice when it comes to bar charts. also the mailing list is very active and there is constant development going on

Answer (score 5):

with [PSTricks](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=Examples/Charts/chart) you can have also 3D charts with hidden surfaces

Answer (score 5):

To keep in line with previous answers, you can look at [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) or [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/), though I guess it might be easier to use a combination of [R](http://www.r-project.org/) and [Sweave](http://www.stat.uni-muenchen.de/~leisch/Sweave/) for that particular purpose, especially if you want to load your data from an external file (but see related questions tagged [`sweave`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sweave)).

Comment: +1 for Sweave. If you are independently using R for your statistics, then it makes sense to be using it for charts in your documents.  There's also the great TikZDevice package for R. (https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=440)

Comment: @Alan Thank you. I forgot about this package.

Answer (score 4):

I can't seem to be able to correctly format multiline code in a comment, thus I'm adding another answer voting for [PGF/TikZ](http://pgf.sourceforge.net/), it's great!

Here's an (slightly adapted :) example of a plot I recently made with [pgfplots](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ylabel={Some Label [\%]},
            ybar,
            bar width=62pt,
            xtick=data,
            xticklabel={Something},
            legend style={at={(0.05,0.62)},anchor=north west}
            ]       
        \addplot coordinates {(0,13)};
        \addplot coordinates {(0,42)};
        \legend{First Thing,Second Thing}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

Comment: it is giving me this error - ! Undefined control sequence.
\pr@ship@end ...n@ii =\dimen@ \global \pdfvorigin 
                                                  \dimen@ \dimen@ \dp \pr@bo...
l.20 \end{preview} not sure what am i doing wrong

Comment: It does run for me with pdfLaTeX, both on Windows and Mac... You can maybe try to remove the `\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}` as well as both the `\begin{preview}` and `\end{preview}` as this only produces a cropped pdf...

Answer (score 1):

I would use pgf/TikZ too, just like other users who answered.

There are some really old packages [`bar`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bar), [`barkom`](http://ctan.org/pkg/barkom). An newer one, worth a try, is [`bardiag`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bardiag), based on PSTricks.

A PSTricks package for this purpose is [`pst-bar`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-bar).